# Prevent Replacing session in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a problem in codeigniter session, when i logged In, the system is working and session is set but when i open a new tab in the browser and log in again the current session is replaced by the newly logged session. what I want to achieve is to redirect directly into the home page if the session is set and proceed to login page if session is not set.

I did research some fix for this, somehow I try this but it didn't work as expected.

Controller:

```
public function index(){

    if(isset($_SESSION['Username'])){
        redirect('Isidran/home' , 'refresh');
    } else {

        $data['title'] = 'Isidran Club and Organization Online Information System - Login';
        $this->load->view('pages/login/index', $data);  
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function login($data) 
    {

        $username = $data['username'];
        $password = $data['password'];
        $query =$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_Username ='$username' AND user_Password ='$password'");
        $row =$query->row();
        if(isset($row)){
            $user_ID   =$row->user_ID;
            $username =$row->user_Username;
            $FirstName=$row->user_FirstName;
            $LastName = $row->user_LastName;
            if($row->user_level == 0){
                $permission = TRUE;
                $userdata = array( 'user_ID' => $user_ID, 'Username' => $username, 'FirstName' => $FirstName, 'LastName' => $LastName, 'logged_in' => TRUE, 'permission' => $permission); 
            } else {
                $userdata = array( 'user_ID' => $user_ID, 'Username' => $username, 'FirstName' => $FirstName, 'LastName' => $LastName, 'logged_in' => TRUE); 
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
        return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In controller also use the CI Session library

Answer (score 1):

Use following for setting your session data, pass data in array to ($session_data)

```
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
```

and following for checking if sessions exist

```
if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])) {
URL
}
```

Use above if statement at login page or make your own logic to check each page in view.

Read the following full method of use session

https://www.formget.com/form-login-codeigniter/